# How to Choose Cell Adjacent to the Max Number in a Row

Tags: excel

I have a tricky one. I need to find the content of a cell to the right of a max number in a given row. My example below: In each column there are test scores that alternate with the date they were taken. I need to find the maximum score in a row, then show the date the test was taken (the cell to the right):

```
Student1   6.2 4/12/2015   8.5 11/21/2013   12.2 7/5/2015
Student2   5.5 3/11/2014   7.6 10/10/2011   11.2 6/15/2012
```

So I'm able to isolate the max score via a pivot table, but I can't pull the associated date related to the max score...In this case, I would need a formula that gives me 7/5/2015 for student1 and 6/15/2012 for student 2 since those are dates of the test taken when the highest score was achieved.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a screen shot for more clarity

Answer (score 1):

If the sample data above is in columns A to G, with labels in row 1 and data starting in row 2, then you can use a formula like

=Index(B2:G2,match(max(B2,D2,F2),B2:G2,0)+1)